# Problem implementing Attentive Pooling Network for Question Answering

Tags: matrix, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm following [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03609) paper to implement and Attentive Pooling Network to build a Question Answering system. In chapter 2.1, it speaks about the CNN layer:

[image: Extract from the original paper, chapter 2.1]

where `q_emb` is a question where each token (word) has been embedded using word2vec. `q_emb` has shape `(d, M)`. `d` is the dimension of the word embedding and `M` the length of the question. In a similar way, `a_emb` is the embedding of the answer with shape `(d, L)`.
My question is: how is the convolution done and how is it possible that `W_1` and `b_1` are the same for both the operations? In my opinion at least `b_1` should have a different dimension in each case (and it should be a matrix, not a vector....).

At the moment I've implemented this operation in PyTorch:

```
### Input is a tensor of shape (batch_size, 1, M or L, d*k)
conv2 = nn.Conv2d(1, c, (d*k, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that the authors of the paper are trusting the readers to assume/figure out a lot of things here. From what I read, here is what I could gather:

1. `W1` should be a `1 X dk` matrix because that is the only shape that would make sense in order to get `Q` as `c X M` matrix.
2. Assuming this, `b1` need not be an matrix. From the above, you could get a `c X 1 X M` matrix which could be reshaped to `c X M` matrix easily and `b1` could be a `c X 1` vector which could be broadcasted and added to the rest of the matrix.

Since, `c`, `d` and `k` are hyper parameters, you could easily have the same `W1` and `b1` for both `Q` and `A`.

This is what I think so far, I will re read and edit in case anythings amiss.